# Best Troubleshooting builder tool

Tags: help-desk

We have a CMS builder in our company which is managed by business guys, the problem is for every issue they come to development team, and 90% of issue are not related to code (configurations and settings and pages, articles, language... in CMS)

I was thinking if there was a troubleshooting application could help dev team a lot, since when the business guys had a problem they would first go to that app and based on questions and answers they would get a proper solution or at least made them check the initial things, and if they still have the problem then they send ticket to dev team. (Something like windows troubleshooting tool)

I searched the net I couldn't find a "Troubleshooting Builder Tool", I was wondering if somebody has the same problem or somebody knows a good tool for that?

Comment: Possibly a bunch of generic browser test scripts? built with

Comment: What OS must be supported? What features do you need ("best" is very subjective: One man's owl is another man's nightingale)? What is your budget? Any license specific requirements? Please [edit] your question and add those details. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize, don't you, that no matter what you give them, their ***first*** action is ***always*** going to be to come directly to the developers?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called an [expert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system). You may get better search results with that search term

Comment: While you might not be looking for an academic solution, you should consider getting a game called "[20 questions](http://www.englishhints.com/question-game.html)" (or so) where your answers get filled into a database. Instead of adding animals and stuff, you add questions like "Does the config file X contain Y?"

Comment: A good phrase to Google would be "wizard builder"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a generic “trouble-shooter builder”, and presume that you have Googled.

Since this is going to have to be a bespoke solution, tailored to your CMS and its use cases, I would suggest that you code a bunch of browser scripts, built with [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) (which is the most popular, hence well supported and documented, and quite usable, generic browser (test) scripting language),   and tailored to your CMS.

You could code the scripts to do the troubleshooting that you normally have to do manually, and  have them report problems and solutions directly to the business guys in pop-ups.

In that way, they should be running the trouble-shooter, acting on its advice and not coming to bother you developers.

Comment: Selenium is a web app test tool, right? How do I build a expert system for my C# desktop program with it?

Comment: huh? where did C# come from? I don't see it in the original question. Yes, Selenium is for testing browser apps, but since it drives the browser, it can be scripted to walk through a wizard. Ah! that's what the OP wants - a wizard builder.